# Read in a file in R up to a designated point

Tags: r, file

I want to be able to read in a .txt file into R which is always going to be a `n` by 2 file (`n` rows and 2 columns). I don't know how big `n` is each time but at the end of the file it breaks into just one column, so the end of the file may look like this :

```
abc       500
def       600
---       0 
Total     0
---       0
```

Ideally I would like to stop reading in when we hit the `----`. This is always consistent, so read in but stop when you get to `----`.

Comment: What command are you currently using to read in the file?

Comment: just trying the read.table("xyz.txt") - but because the after the second set of ----  the format breaks into a bunch of 0's which are only in coloumn 2 - i get an error message   "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 47 did not have 2 elements" - which is correct because after a certain amount of rows we do get to a place where we have only elements in one coloumn. if however we can read up to the line with "----" then we will avoid that problem while always getting in all the required data

Comment: That's not consistent with the example file layout you included in your question. What you currently have works fine with `read.table("xyz.txt")`.

Comment: Either way,  `fill=TRUE` will take care of the problem.

Comment: thanks Carl - the table is as above but underneath the 0's there are a whole lot more zeros' with nothing in column one hence my error message. your fill = TRUE works fine and populates the table with NA's where there is nothing - I would if possible still like to fill only till we hit the "----" if possible rather than take in the whole thing